# UntTest - Mock RxJava object in UseCase Object

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java

I want to test UseCase object, in this specific case there is a LoginUseCase, which looks like this:

```
public class LoginUseCase implements RxUseCase<AuthResponse, AuthCredentials> {

    ApiManager mApiManager;

    public LoginUseCase(ApiManager apiManager) {
        mApiManager =apiManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<AuthResponse> execute(final AuthCredentials authCredentials) {
        return Observable.just(1)
                .delay(750, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .flatMap(l -> mApiManager.login(authCredentials.getLogin(), authCredentials.getPassword()));
    }
}
```

I wrote simple test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginUseCaseTest {

    private LoginUseCase mLoginUseCase;
    @Mock ApiManager mApiManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mLoginUseCase = new LoginUseCase(mApiManager);
    }


    @Test
    public void testShouldThrowsError() throws Exception {
        TestSubscriber<AuthResponse> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
        doReturn(Observable.error(new Throwable())).when(mApiManager).login("", "");
        mLoginUseCase
            .execute(new AuthCredentials("", ""))
            .subscribe(testSubscriber);
        testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();

    }
}
```

But this test always passes and I don't know how mock error observable in this case.

**EDIT**: I've chaged testShouldThrowsError() according to SkinnyJ, but test still passes, any sugestions?

Comment: Even though I don't know, why you need a delay here, but you can use http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html operator instead of just + delay, which would be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `awaitTerminalEvent()` on your test subscriber before assertions.
Because now, you schedule a delay to be run on `Schedulers.computation` and your test method successfully completes before completion of observable.

Alternative approach would be to pass scheduler as argument to `execute` method, or store scheduler in your usecase. This way, during test you can pass `Schedulers.immediate()` and your test will run on current thread (which will block execution for specified delay).

And last approach is to call `toBlocking()` on observable, but I think that passing scheduler is preferred choice. And there is no way to add this operator to your current observable.