# How to make retrofit observable synchronous

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2

I am facing an issue while writing test cases for an retrofit call.

I want to make retrofit observable synchronous so that test case passes. Currently test case execution is getting completed before retrofit callback comes and hence test case is failing.

Here is the retrofit call:

```
**TestClient.getWeatherData(cityName)
    .observeOn(mainThreadSched)
    .subscribeOn(ioSched)
    .subscribe(this::onLoadSuccess, this::onLoadError);**
```

I am using Dagger to inject differnet schedulers for actual and test code as follows:

```
mainThreadSched set to **AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()** and 
ioSche set to **Schedulers.io()**
```

For test code:

```
mainThreadSched set to **Schedulers.immediate()** and 
ioSched set to **Schedulers.immediate()**
```

still sometimes test case is failing though setting scheduler to `Schedulers.immediate()`. I am doing something wrong here? or is there any alternative way to do this testing?

Comment: Did you try with `Schedulers.trampoline()`? `immediate` is prone to misterious hangs because it's not a proper scheduler (sleeps and doesn't support recursive/reentrant use).

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873806/unttest-mock-rxjava-object-in-usecase-object

You can use `toBlocking` or use `TestSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent()`.

Comment: remove `subscribeOn(ioSched)` from your code. So everything will be call from main thread itself

Answer (score 0):

You can append toBlock().first() to Observable.